# Anyone can ID this "FCI" connector in a Fiat 500 parking light?

Tags: connector, identification

I'm looking to replace the terminals but can't even ID the connector. Can get a connector kit from the dealer for $70 but just need one 50 cent terminal.

[image: http://www.fototime.com/670C629F0440EBF/large.jpg]

[image: http://www.fototime.com/EBA26E4E8C67FDA/large.jpg]

Comment: This might be one of those cases where a wrecking yard is your best option. Jeep Cherokee seems to use a similar connector.

Comment: Yes that is my second choice. I got the light itself from the junkyard but didn't think I would need the connector then.

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for nearly the same connector (black instead of green) for fixing a problem on my Fiat Panda and also had only found quite expensive connectors and adapters for down to 20 Euros.
The number "PA66..." on the violet plate has mislead me a little.
It is the number of the used plastic material...

Finally I found on a distributors site (automotive-connectors com) only the violet "secondary lock" with the number "FCI 17260874". 
For this I found 17260851, the male counterpart of the connector housing on the photo. A little more searching and I found the female variant...

The 17260855 should be the green female housing as on the photo, with 17260879, the secondary lock. The part numbers 211CC2S2161 and 17062010 are examples for the crimp connectors (taken from the datasheet of the connector housing). 
They seem to be the same as in the infamous grey connector (headlights failed) on the Fiat Panda body computer.
The part numbers may help to find the data sheets provided by the electronics distributor with the "M".

BTW: according to the data sheets, both connector sides should have a silicon gasket. I hope these were not forgotten by Fiat during assembly...